# Running java program in windows which is compiled in linux

Tags: java

I compiled java program in fedora12.I could execute it successfully in fedora.I copied .class to Windows XP environment and tried to execute.I got class Not Found exception.why ? what could be the reasons ?

Comment: Please post the complete error.

Comment: Sounds like you might be missing a package, can you tell us what class isn't found?

Comment: Thanks for your replies.I resolved the problem(problem with environmental variables.

Answer (score 0):

You probably compiled the program in a newer version of the JDK than the one installed in the Window box. Post the details here so that we can help.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify a classpath, note that in Windows the entries are separated by semicolon rather than colon (even under Cygwin):

- Linux: `java -cp lib/a.jar:lib/b.jar myMain`
- Windows: `java -cp lib/a.jar;lib/b.jar myMain`

Comment: Why would Cygwin make a difference there? Java is a normal Windows program and naturally doesn't share the Cygwin model of paths or lists of paths.